# sencha touch local storage saving

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

i am trying to use the sencha touch local storage, i can sync and display the updated data, but once the app is close the data is gone, here is my code below

```
var localstore = Ext.getStore('LocalLogStore');
    var index = localstore.findExact('UserID', 1);
    record = localstore.getAt(index);
    if (obj.results.apiKey) {
    record.set('apikey', obj.results.apiKey);
    record.set('SessionID', obj.results.sessionKey);
    record.set('AutoLog', 1);
    localstore.sync();
```

any help would be great

thank you advance

Jason

Answer (score 0):

How you are defining store, If you can paste your sample code.
you can define store proxy type localStorage then it will keep your data.

Ex.

```
    Ext.define('ProjectName.store.YourStore', {
     extend:'Ext.data.Store',
     config:{
     autoLoad: true,
      model: "User",
     proxy: {
        type: 'localStorage',

        reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'users'
      }
  }}
});
```

Comment: thank you for that, yes I have done a store for it, i have sorted out what the problem is, i have some static data in the store, which it seems impossible to update, soon as i removed that static data everything works great, and cheers for your help Amar